# Karlin-Rubin theorem and exponential family

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, inference, exponential-family

> Let $X_1,...X_n$ a random sample of $X$ with density
>   $$f(x;\alpha,\beta)=\frac{\alpha}{x^{\alpha+1}}\beta^\alpha
>  I_{[\beta,\infty]}(x)\space\alpha>0,\beta>0$$ with $\beta$ known.
>
> Find a UMP test for $H_0:\alpha=\alpha_0$ vs $H_1:\alpha>\alpha_0$

$$f(x;\alpha,\beta)=\alpha\beta^\alpha I_{[\beta,\infty]}(x)e^{-(\alpha+1)\log x}=a(\alpha)b(x)e^{c(\alpha)d(x)}$$ $$a(\alpha)=\alpha\beta^\alpha\space,b(x)=I_{[\beta,\infty]}\space,c(\alpha)=-(\alpha+1), d(x)=\log x$$

then I know that $f(x;\alpha,\beta)$ belongs to exponential family, from Casella & Berger's [*Statistical Inference*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0534243126),

> $f(x;\alpha,\beta)$ have MLR(monotone likelihood-ratio) if $c(\alpha)$
>   is a nondecreasing function

, but this is not the case, since $-(\alpha+1)$ is monotone decreasing function.

I know that to apply the theorem of Karlin-Rubin the distribution of sufficient statistic $T$ need to have nondecreasing MLR, if this condition is satisfied then the test that rejects $H_0$ if and only if $T>T_0$ is a UMP level $\alpha$ test , where $\alpha=P_{\theta_0}(T>t_0)$.

I did not check if $T=\sum\log x$ have nondecreasing MLR, because the fact about the exponential family left me quite confused.

I can apply the karlin-Rubin theorem in this case, how would the critical region of my test?

Comment: @Xi'an This is just a standard notation we use to show that it is exponential family

Comment: @John It is not standard to the rest of the world.

Comment: @whuber I have already explained what it is

Comment: You have given formulas, but those do not explain the meanings of those functions or their roles in this question. Doing so is important for communicating your question to others and also for detecting errors. For example, you have written "$c(\alpha)=-(a+1)$" and "$a(\alpha)=\alpha\beta^\alpha$." Does that mean (plugging the second into the first) that $c(\alpha) = -(\alpha\beta^\alpha + 1)$? How is anybody to know whether that's the case or whether "$a$" is a typo for "$\alpha$" in the formula for $c$, if you do not state what $c$ is intended to mean?

Comment: @whuber I improved the statement, I think now everything is clear.

Comment: The notation is now apparent, thank you. In looking over the post, though, I haven't found an answerable question yet: you only assert that you don't understand something. Could you be more specific about what you are asking, so that your readers have some idea what to direct their attention towards?

Comment: @whuber Edited again, my question is in the last paragraph,it's about the critical region.

Comment: Can you show us how you derive the critical region by applying Karlin-Rubin to this exponential family, i.e., by finding how the likelihood ratio is monotone?

Comment: I think you're confusing yourself with $c$ and $d$, which you don't need at all.  They merely reparametrize the support and parameters.  It's easier to work with natural parameters (no $c$) and in the most obvious space (no $d$).

Comment: @NeilG Maybe, what confuses me is if I take $c(\alpha)=(a+1)$ and $d(x)=-\log x$ then $c$ is a nondecreasing function and $f$ has MLR.

Comment: @JohnSheridan: Why can't $c$ be nondecreasing?  If using $c$ is an exponential family, then so is $-c$.  Just as using a Gaussian parametrized by mean and variance is an exponential family, and so is one parametrized by negative mean and variance.

Comment: If $c(\alpha)$ is monotone decreasing, what about re-parametrising your exponential family in $(\tilde{c}(\cdot),\tilde{T}(\cdot))=(-c(\cdot),-T(\cdot))$? Then $\tilde{c}$ is monotone increasing and you can apply the Karlin-Rubin lemma to $\tilde{T}$.

Comment: @Xi'an I thought about that too, and the critical region will be $T>t_0$ for some constant $t_0$?

Comment: No, it would be $-T>t_0$, which is equivalent to $T<-t_0$.